# Prove $\frac{x^2}{a} +\frac{y^2}{b} \ge \frac{(x+y)^2}{a+b}$

Tags: inequality

How do I prove $\frac{x^2}{a} +\frac{y^2}{b} \ge \frac{(x+y)^2}{a+b}$

x,y $\in$ R and a,b $\in R^+$

Thanks.

Comment: $greater or equal$ is `\ge` in Latex (think to the initial letters)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Sedrakyan's_lemma_-_Positive_real_numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x, y \in \mathbb R$ and $a,b \in (0,\infty)$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{b}-\frac{x^2+y^2}{a+b}&
=\frac{b(a+b)x^2+a(a+b)y^2-ab(x+y)^2}{ab(a+b)} \\
&=\frac{b^2x^2+a^2y^2-2abxy}{ab(a+b)} \\
&=\frac{(bx-ay)^2}{ab(a+b)}\geq 0,
\end{align}
therefore
$$
\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{b}\geq\frac{x^2+y^2}{a+b}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{x^2}{a} +\frac{y^2}{b} \ge \frac{(x+y)^2}{a+b}\Rightarrow\\\frac{bx^2+ay^2}{ab}\ge\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{a+b}$$

but since  $a,b\gt0$, by multiplying with $ab(a+b)$ we have:

$$abx^2+a^2y^2+b^2x^2+ab^2\ge abx^2+2abxy+aby^2\Rightarrow\\a^2y^2+b^2x^2\ge2abxy\Rightarrow\\(ay-bx)^2\ge0$$

which is indeed true $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.